bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS even though it is active and running
I have Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS installed on a dell desktop computer. The bluetooth used to work on this device but does not anymore because I played around with it a couple of years ago (and I don't remember what I did, so apologies). Now the blueooth icon does not show in the panel. It shows up in the settings, but I cannot turn it on.
When I run sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status, I see the bluetooth is active:
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-12-11 13:42:00 CET; 2h 2min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 18957 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19038)
     Memory: 664.0K
        CPU: 54ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─18957 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

I also think the adaptor is working fine; when I run rfkill list all, I see:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

when I run sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm', I see:
[    0.150918] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   22.091431] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.091457] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   22.091458] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.091462] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.091464] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.091469] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.747314] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   22.748324] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   22.764455] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   22.764470] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   23.005393] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   23.005401] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[   23.005403] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21d7.hcd'
[   25.033290] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   25.033290] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x1003 failed: -110
[   39.774503] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   39.774506] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   39.774509] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 4153.411582] Modules linked in: bnep nvidia_uvm(PO) binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek nvidia_drm(PO) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg btusb snd_intel_sdw_acpi btrtl btintel btbcm nvidia(PO) snd_hda_codec btmtk snd_hda_core bluetooth intel_rapl_msr mei_pxp mei_hdcp intel_rapl_common snd_hwdep snd_pcm x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event coretemp ecdh_generic snd_rawmidi wl(POE) snd_seq kvm_intel ecc joydev dell_wmi snd_seq_device input_leds dell_smbios snd_timer kvm dell_wmi_descriptor ledtrig_audio cmdlinepart sparse_keymap spi_nor mei_me dcdbas snd cfg80211 irqbypass mei mtd dell_smm_hwmon soundcore crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 at24 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl intel_cstate mac_hid nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_masq nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink
[25769.663464] Modules linked in: bnep nvidia_uvm(PO) binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek nvidia_drm(PO) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg btusb snd_intel_sdw_acpi btrtl btintel btbcm nvidia(PO) snd_hda_codec btmtk snd_hda_core bluetooth intel_rapl_msr mei_pxp mei_hdcp intel_rapl_common snd_hwdep snd_pcm x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event coretemp ecdh_generic snd_rawmidi wl(POE) snd_seq kvm_intel ecc joydev dell_wmi snd_seq_device input_leds dell_smbios snd_timer kvm dell_wmi_descriptor ledtrig_audio cmdlinepart sparse_keymap spi_nor mei_me dcdbas snd cfg80211 irqbypass mei mtd dell_smm_hwmon soundcore crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 at24 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl intel_cstate mac_hid nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_masq nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink

I have blueman installed but with no success.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you.

Please edit to include results from terminal for sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Hello @Jeremy31, thank you for your hint. The firmware patch was not found, so I downloaded it and copied it in the right place from here: link and now bluetooth is working.
